# Finite groups with number of generators strictly less than number of relations

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

For the finite cyclic group of order $n$, there is the standard presentation $\langle a \mid a^n\rangle$. Also for $S_n$ (symmetric group), I know a few presentations where the number of relations is strictly bigger than the number of generators.

I want to get examples of $G$, where $G$ is a finite group with the property that for any presentation of $G$ the number of relations is strictly bigger than the number of generators.

More generally, can one put some condition on a finite group $G$, so that for any presentation the number of relations is strictly bigger than the number of generators?

Comment: TeX note: please use $\langle\rangle$ `\langle\rangle` instead of $<>$ `<>`.  It is also often preferable (though, unlike `\langle\rangle`, probably not universally agreed) to use `\mid` for a divider rather than `|`.  (The results are $\langle a \mid a^n\rangle$ vs. $<a|a^n>$.)  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: You should read about  the Golod-Shafarevich inequality.

Comment: $(\mathbb Z/p)^n$ is an example for all $n>1$, which can be proven using mod $p$ cohomology.

Comment: The lingo for this kind of thing is deficiency.

Comment: In general the "quest" is rather to find groups of deficiency zero among finite groups. See for instance [this 1996 paper](https://staff.itee.uq.edu.au/havas/TR0315.pdf) by Havas, Newman, and O'Brien. They mention in particular that a theorem of Golod-Shafarevich says that a finite $p$-group with deficiency zero is 3-generated (whether this holds for all finite groups is mentioned there as open).

Comment: And in general (with the |relators|$-$|generators| sign convention) the deficiency of a finite group is $\ge$ that of its Schur multiplier. See also [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02040) by Gardam (publ. Bull LMS 2017) for examples of finite groups with arbitrary positive deficiency.

Comment: @YCor: your second comment seems like it would make a pretty good answer to me!